# Testing with JUnit a void method

Tags: java, junit

I have the following code, and I dont know how to test it.

I was trying to access the count contD++, and if i have 3 negatives.

I cant test it with something like this `assertEquals(contD,3)`

```
public void listarD() {
    int contD = 0;

    for(int i=0; i< clientes.length; i++) {
        if(clientes[i].getSaldo() < 0) {
            System.out.println(
                    "Cliente: " + clientes[i].getNombre() + 
                    ". Saldo: " + clientes[i].getSaldo());
            contD++;
        }
    }

    if (contD == 0) {
        System.out.println("No hay descubiertos :D");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("TOTAL DESCUBIERTOS: " + contadorDescubiertos + " clientes");
    }       
}
```

Comment: You can not test a void in this way. You have to refactor your code

Comment: If you cannot test your code properly, then this is an indication of bad design.

Comment: @Bevor the concept behind bad design is much deaper than just a simple test

Answer (score 3):

Correct way would be to extract a method that calculates your `contD` value and test it.

```
public void listarD() {

    int contD = calculateContD();

    if (contD == 0) {
        ...
    }    
}
```

And then you can test this `calculateContD()` method.

Answer (score 3):

A well designed method should be easy to test, the fact that you cannot test your method is an evidence of a design flaw.

Some suggestions:

- Make the result of the method verifiable (That could imply that it's
  no longer void).
- Leave the output on a permanent storage, like disk
  or database.

Answer (score 2):

There is one way you could *theoretically* test this: one can **change** the object behind System.out.

So, *theoretically*, you could put a "special" OutputStream into System.out; run your void method; and then check that the messages you would expect ... show up in that stream of yours.

But that simply makes no (t much) sense: you see, in the real world, you rarely do print to system.out. In the real world, your methods either

- do return a value
- make calls on **other** objects
- change some internal state of the enclosing object/class

Thus: in the real world, you write tests that care about such kind of events.

So, as you figured yourself; the real answer is to change the behavior of your void method; by returning the value it computed already!

Answer (score 0):

In general, a function that can only be verified by human eyes is not a good design. Callers would never know what happened after they call your function. Either a return value or an exception for denoting the result is better than nothing.